# Flutter module grade files keep resetting

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

I’ve installed Firebase authentication on my flutter app and whenever I load Android studio after it has been shut down and run my android app, I get the error Multidex must be enabled and when I check the .android files, I find my google-services.json file has been deleted and the gradle settings are not how I initially left them, more less like it’s been reset.
I always ensure I have saved my project before shutting down but now I can’t figure out what do. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your app/build.gradle file add this line

```
     defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

Don't forget to call after that :

```
flutter clean
flutter doctor
```